# EFI Partition not taking up full space

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot, efi

I originally installed Windows onto my computer, so it had the default 100MB EFI Partition. Recently, I wanted to dual boot Arch and Windows 11, so I resized the partition from 100MB to 598MB (an arbitrary number). However, I checked my available space using command prompt, and it shows there's only 96MB of total space. Is there something I need to do to use the full space?
[Command Prompt disk space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOuuN.png)
[Disk Management disk space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4StNs.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have increased the allocation for the EFI partition,
but you have not resized the file-system in the partition.
This is why Disk Management reports 598 MB, while `fsutil` still
reports the old value of 96 MB.

To correctly resize the partition, you need to resize it from a
bootable USB media using a third-party product that will resize
both the partition and its file-system.

Ensure you have good backups before doing any partition editing.

For more information see the post
[How to enlarge Windows 10 EFI partition](https://superuser.com/questions/1106092/how-to-enlarge-windows-10-efi-partition).