# Moving recovery partition

Tags: windows, partitioning

I bought a new SSD and cloned my existing HDD on that SSD, but now I recognized that I have a bit strange order of the partitions:

System-Reserved (~350MB), Windows (~150GB), Recovery (~534MB), nothing (~50GB), Data (~700GB) and again nothing (~900GB).

I would like to increase the Windows partition however that unexpected Recovery partition is preventing this. I'm wondering if I can move the recovery partition to the end of the ssd so that I have more room for new or other partitions? To be honest I have no idea how that recovery partition is linked and if it matters if that partition moved to a later "index".

Comment: You can indeed move the partition.  You would have to use a third-party disk partitioning to do that.  You should of course take the steps to backup any critical data.  I will not provide a recommendation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want to expand a partition on my boot SSD, but there is a Recovery Partition and EFI System Partition in the way. How can I get around this?](https://superuser.com/questions/972227/i-want-to-expand-a-partition-on-my-boot-ssd-but-there-is-a-recovery-partition-a)

Comment: Not really to be honest. I'm not sure what steps I need to do to make sure that the recovery partition is still working when I moved it. I'm right now thinking that resizing the Windows partition is the best option and then moving or copying the recovery partition into the new free room. So that the order is system reserved, recovery and then windows. I have in mind that I there must be a link in the MBR to make the system boot.

Comment: In order to do that you will have to use a third-party drive partition software

Comment: I'm aware of this, but this still doesn't answer if just moving and resizing partitions is all to make it still working afterwards.

Comment: So a question with a detailed answer that explains how to move the recovery partition doesn’t answer your question?  What step are you stuck on exactly?

Comment: Right now I'm moving and resizing partitions on good luck, but I think that when the operation is done, that my computer won't boot from my ssd since the MBR points to the wrong sector or so. I just don't believe that it is so easy.

Comment: Why do you believe your HDD is MBR instead of GPT?

Comment: Basically because that partition software told me so. I'm not really aware about the differences. I just know that GPT is newer

Comment: As expected my computer cannot boot from the ssd now.

Comment: Moving the recovery partition shouldn’t have caused that.

Comment: My partitions are now System Reserved, recovery, windows (increased to 250GB) and data aligned so that there is no gab before but still unallocated space at the end

Comment: Once in Windows, you should be able to extend the system disk into the unallocated space.  The only task that Disk Management cannot do is move partitions.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware about that restrictions. However my computer doesn't boot now and I need to find out how I can fix that. I would expect something like a fix MBR command. I need to create a bootable usb stick to "rescue" my system. I would like to see some guidance regarding the actual repair steps.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-the-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows/1444266#1444266) should be helpful

Comment: No that doesn't work either. Now I get an error 225 on booting