# Windows 10 boot corruption

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, uefi, bootloader

I have an Asus laptop with Win10 installed. I previously had a distro of Linux installed with its own GRUB. Today, I decided to change the Linux distro, but I first checked whether Win10 UEFI was still there. It's not.

I tried unsuccessfully to recover it from Windows. When I rebooted the PC, I started having troubles. It said, "no operating system found" just after the Asus logo disappeared.

I had a CD with Ubuntu and I tried to start a live session to see what wasn't working. All partitions were OK, so I tried to remove other Linux partitions (thought it was a GRUB conflict). I also tried to repair the Windows MBR with syslinux. All I got when I restarted was another prompt-style error message saying "Reboot and Select proper Boot device or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press any key".

This is my situation, I have no UEFI to access in safe mode for Windows, I have BCD problems on Windows, and I have no Windows installation CD.  The HDD is correctly read in the BIOS menu and is correctly set as the first boot option.

When I was on Ubuntu live, I saw that all Windows files could be read, and all partitions were okay and working.  However, I used Gparted and now the file system of Windows is corrupted.  I did find another Win10 installation CD, but it is for another type of Windows 10.

What should I do to recover Win10 without loss of data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Repair Windows 10 boot loader](https://superuser.com/questions/987822/repair-windows-10-boot-loader)

Comment: It appears that you need to install from scratch, using the option to save user files and settings if available; if not you'll need to recover files from your latest back-up. Down-load the Windows 10 ISO from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO), then create a bootable installation disc (DVD or USB disc). You may want to try to save what you can from the existing disc first.

Comment: Similar to AFH, I suggest booting from a LiveCD, copying all data to an external HD, then formatting and starting over.  For the future, whenever making bootstrapper changes, Linux distro changes, anything that could make the machine unbootable, etc, always back up everything important in an easy-to-restore fashion first.  Hard to know what's dangerous until you've tried it, and harder to figure out what data is important to you until you've lost it. :(

Comment: Thanks to all, but I already decided to just uninstall all and install a new version of win 10 and a Ubuntu iso, I made a clean reset of all. A good restart from the beginning, next time I will be more careful, thanks to all