# Unable to start Windows without several reboots after installing (and than uninstalling) Ubuntu as a secondary OS

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows-10, hardware-failure

When I start the PC, screen displays the Asus (motherboard) logo, then the screen goes black and becomes inactive.
If I restart the PC couple of times, it will finally load Windows.

It began when I installed Ubuntu as a second OS.
I have unistalled Ubuntu, but it didn't help.

Comment: After this I tried to switch off and on Monitor,
and you know, for half of a second I can see my work table, but than picture again goes black and become inactive.
After 3 or 4 times turn off/on monitor it become to work normally)

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a GRUB problem – when you installed Ubuntu, GRUB didn't find your Windows partition. If you like to stay just with Windows, use the below instructions from [the Microsoft Knowledge Base](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392) to fix Windows boot.

> To run the Bootrec.exe tool, first start the Windows RE (Recovery Environment):
>
> 1. Put the Windows Vista or Windows 7 media in the DVD drive, and then start the computer.
> 2. Press a key when you are prompted.
> 3. Select a language, a time, a currency, a keyboard, or an input method, and then click **Next**.
> 4. Click **Repair your computer**.
> 5. Select the operating system that you want to repair, and then click **Next**.
> 6. In the **System Recovery Options** dialog box, click **Command Prompt**.
> 7. Type `Bootrec.exe`, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
>
> **Note** To start the computer from the Windows Vista or Windows 7 DVD,
>   the computer must be configured to start from the DVD drive. 
>   For information about how to do this,
>   see the documentation that was included with the computer,
>   or contact the computer manufacturer.

Edit: bootrec doesn't work in Windows 10. 
Check [How to fix Windows 10 boot loader from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows)
if bootrec doesn't work.

Comment: I tried, and it did not help.
I add coment for question, and maybe you now know what can be wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that your monitor is working properly? Did you test it?

Comment: No, I think it posibly can be something wrong with it
I'll try today another monitor