# Microsoft Aniversary update broke my refind bootloader

Tags: windows-10, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I had Windows 10 and Linux installed together. I used UEFI. My setup have been complicated. First I installed Windows, disabled Fast Boot, then installed Manjaro with Grub, but I prefer rEFInd, so I installed it by chroot and removed grub.

It all worked perfect, but after Aniversary Update, when I rebooted I discovered rEFInd was replaced by Windows Bootloader, also Fast Boot was enabled again.

To fix it, I chrooted and installed refind again. It worked until first Windows boot. When I boot Windows refind was deleted all the time.

I decided to remove all files from efi partition. Installed refind again. But now I cannot boot Windows. I tried to recover windows bootloader by emergency console according to this question:
[How to fix Windows 10 boot loader from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows)

But it don't fix windows boot, instead of my UEFI does not see any bootloader on any partition.

My partitions:

```
sda      8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   300M  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0   100M  0 part /boot/efi
├─sda3   8:3    0   128M  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0 310,5G  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0   450M  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 390,6G  0 part /mnt/1A6D432B224C53B6
├─sda7   8:7    0   221G  0 part /
└─sda8   8:8    0   8,4G  0 part [SWAP]
```

**Question 1: How to recover Windows bootloader if it was completely removed from EFI partition?**

**Question 2: How to force Windows to not breaking my bootloader after updates?**

PS: It's time consuming to recover rEFInd each time. :(

Comment: Somewhere inside here is a question struggling to find its way out.

Comment: I added questions at the end of my story :)

Answer (score 0):

> "I tried to recover windows bootloader by emergency console according
>   to this question: How to fix Windows 10 boot loader from Windows"

is unrelated to UEFI booting. The question answered there is about MBR booting.

---

On UEFI boot sectors and MBR are not used for booting!!

UEFI firmware boot manager is loading OS loaders/boot managers directly!

E.g. UEFI boot manager loads Windows boot manager directly or GRUB (Linux loader) directly.

To fix Windows boot environment you need a simple command:

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s V:
```

where c: is Windows partition, V: is EFI System partition.

**Don't forget to boot Windows recovery USB/DVD the UEFI way!**

Further details - [Repair Windows BCD](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/RepairWindowsBCD.html).

**Notes:**

1) bcdboot fixes complete boot environment (not only BCD).

2) "fast startup" is reset to default on every Windows upgrade!

3) "fast startup" is a Windows setting (in Power options), "fast boot" is firmware setting.