# Windows 10 Hard disk won't boot. Files seem to be fine

Tags: hard-drive, windows-10, boot

One of my PCs just crashed after installing some drivers.  First I got a couple of blue screens stating something like CRITICAL PROCESS ERROR.

After trying a couple of reboots, the PC wouldn't recognize the HD anymore.

Tried to boot from a Windows 10 USB but eventually it just said Your PC/Device needs to be repaired - Error code: 0xc0000098 file: /boot/bcd.  Just an informational screen with no options.

So, I hooked the hard drive up to another PC by a sata to USB cable.  The files are all there (and now are being backed up).

**So, How can fix or restore the drive to be bootable again?**  I would like to this from the second PC, which is working fine and has the drive connected as an external USB drive.  The second PC is running Windows 7.  I have Administrator rights on it too.

I've seen various pages about booting from a CD or USB and doing a repair.  I don't have a CD at the moment and for some reason the USB with a bootable Windows 10 doesn't give me those options.

Answer (score 1):

You might try [these directions](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows) for fixing the Master Boot Record:

> The command in Windows 8/8.1/10 for fixing MBR is "bootsect.exe".
>
> bootsect /nt60 drive_letter: /mbr

However, your statement "Tried to boot from a Windows 10 USB but eventually it just said Your PC/Device needs to be repaired," indicates there might be a more serious issue than just the boot record.

Check that the PC does not have other issues by booting from a stand-alone USB flash drive OS, such as Windows PE or Linux. *If the PC cannot boot from a flash drive, you may have BIOS (UEFI) or hardware issues that need to be fixed before the OS can be repaired.* Follow directions for setting up your particular BIOS to boot from USB: you may need to disable Fast Boot and/or Secure Boot, change boot order, and enable legacy (default) boot from USB.

You can get Windows PE from Microsoft, or create a bootable rescue drive with Macrium Reflect or similar tool... BTW, if you've *imaged* your HDD while it was healthy, restoring everything, including boot partition, is easy using Reflect or other imaging tool rescue disk.

[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/) can be run directly from the USB, or it can be installed by itself or with Windows on you HDD.

Comment: This utility is not available in Windows 7 (or less) by default.  Apparently, the utility is on installation CD.  Which I don't have at the moment.  So, I found a few places over the web to download it, such as: https://www.kyleabaker.com/2011/12/29/create-a-bootable-windows-7-x64-install-flash-drive-from-32-bit-window/

Comment: Oh and it worked too.  The drive is booting up fine now.