# how to get boot parameters for GPT with UEFI

Tags: windows, multi-boot, uefi, gpt, efi

Wikipedia redirects "Windows Boot Manager" to the [Windows Vista Startup Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_startup_process).  To avoid a [problem dual booting Windows 10 with Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows), I would want to note the UEFI and GPT configuration from a live Linux flash drive.  I'm not sure what the Windows equivalent to GRUB 2 would be, but I would want to save those settings as well as the partition table.

How do I get that diagnostic data before proceeding with any Linux install steps?

Comment: The only thing of interest are the UEFI boot entries. If you’re concerned about the rest, create an image of the disk.

Answer (score 2):

I think Windows equivalent for GRUB is BOOTMGR or for older versions NTLDR. But, also NTLDR is used for both BOOTMGR and WINLOAD.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read the question again carefully. Your answer does **not** answer the original question.

Comment: Sorry for that, i know. But i don't have reputation (and account :D) for commenting.