# windows 10 is not starting and booting partion empty

Tags: windows-10

Im Windows 10 user. Today it stopped suddenly and stopped booting. I prepared Window 10 rescue pen drive and boot from it. I did automatic fix (no results) plus entered 3 commands from rescue console:

```
bootrec /RebuildBcd
bootrec /fixMbr
bootrec /fixboot
Exit
```

but still no good results.

When I re-entered rescue console I found that disc C is empty (no files) but it's almost full (70 MB free of 1 GB disc).

How to restore booting and data?;)
THanks;).

Update 1: disc has been connected to other machine with windows 8 and partition is visible there. I will do backup and try solution proposed by Tim.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the following: [How to fix Windows 10 boot loader from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/949219/how-to-fix-windows-10-boot-loader-from-windows)

Thats a pretty good instruction and if it doesn't work, you will more than likely need to reinstall

Comment: I will follow but Im wondering why I cannot see files on this drive.

Comment: well.. my guess is you are on the wrong partition/drive. 1GB C: drive? Thats sounds more like the recovery drive or one UEFI boot drives.