# Why does Diskpart tell lies in WinPE?

Tags: partitioning, boot-partition, dism

I'm working on producing a scalable imaging process with Windows Embedded 8.1 Industry pro. The hardware is a small form-factor Jetway PC motherboard with a UEFI compatible BIOS.

I boot the box using a WinPE formatted thumb drive, then run diskpart to provision the disk and format. Once that's done, I transfer the image using DISM and the final step is to run BCDBOOT.

This process works repeatably on several systems.

However, I'm running into issues on Jetway PC motherboards and one of the ways I've used to check that the OS image is bootable is to run DISKPART, then:

```
select disk 0
detail disk
```

I've noticed that DISKPART's output in the WinPE environment shows:

```
SanDisk SD6SB1M128G1022I ATA Device
Disk ID: {9B7710CF-B7E8-4BD4-8887-A4738D22DF0D}
Type   : ATA
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0 
Location Path : ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(SAT0)#ACPI(CHN0)#ATA(C00T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     C   Kiosk_V2     NTFS   Partition    104 GB  Healthy
Volume 1         SYSTEM       FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    Hidden
```

Same system, only when booted into Windows:

```
SanDisk SD6SB1M128G1022I ATA Device
Disk ID: {9B7710CF-B7E8-4BD4-8887-A4738D22DF0D}
Type   : ATA
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : ACPI(_SB_)#ACPI(PCI0)#ACPI(SAT0)#ACPI(CHN0)#ATA(C00T00L00)
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : Yes
Pagefile Disk  : Yes
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : Yes
Clustered Disk  : No

Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
Volume 0     C   Kiosk_V2     NTFS   Partition    104 GB  Healthy    Boot
Volume 1         SYSTEM       FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System
```

So in WinPE, DISKPART apparently doesn't know how to tell if the disk is bootable. Anyone else see this?

**Theory:** Creation of a WinPE thumb drive is forced to 32-bit FAT using the Windows AIK. Since this is a 64-bit machine, maybe there's some problem in the 64-bit UEFI BIOS hand-off of the device info to the 32-bit WinPE OS?

This has cost me several days - looking for anyone with ideas, opinions, experience or just wing-bat crazy suggestions. (Besides giving up...)

Thanks

Comment: The problem with your theory is that all 64-bit machines are 32-bit machines.

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/597004/40928

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> So in WinPE, DISKPART apparently doesn't know how to tell if the disk is bootable. Anyone else see this?

"Boot" doesn't mean the disk is bootable, but it means it's the *boot volume*.  You don't see this in WinPE because it didn't boot off of that disk.

Comment: I feel thoroughly stupid. Yes, quite true. It booted off the WinPE drive, so of course it's not going to say it's the boot disk. I do have a great excuse though, it was a step passed on to me by the motherboard manufacturer! Ha! (Still fails at diverting blame...I should have known better.)

Comment: The terminology is confusing so you can't be faulted IMHO.

Comment: Did I mention this is a GPT disk?  It's a GPT disk on a UEFI system. The basic issue is that I can only get the process to work if I set the SATA mode to IDE and format as GPT with an EFI partition. I was using DISKPART to check if my BCDBOOT was working or not.

Comment: @Redgum - GPT partitions with Windows requires an EFI partition.  Why you cannot use SATA mode isn't clear that should be your real question.

Comment: You don't *need* a third-party tool to check the *entries* in the MBR, diskpart will show you whether those entries are bootable or not through the "Active" flag. What you *need* a third-party tool for is to check if the MBR contains valid boot code. Also the `clean` command doesn't anything other than wiping everything off the disk. It's more likely to make it *unbootable* since it erases *all* flags.

Comment: Ramhound - I understand that. There is actually an underlying problem somewhere, but my post was designed to address one specific symptom and that's been done. The SATA mode in BIOS can be set to IDE or AHCI.  I may end up posting the problem/question, but I'm still collecting data.

Comment: ultrasawblade ?