# WinPE DiskPart won't mark volume as active

Tags: boot, partitioning, diskpart, winpe

I have a WinPE flash drive from which I'm trying to use `diskpart` to mark a partition on a system as `active`.

I am able to mark either a partition or a volume as active while in the diskpart tool, and as long as I keep the tool open I can `list` and `select` and do other things all to my heart's content and it will continue show the desired item as active.

However, as soon as I exit diskpart it loses the setting. If I immediately run diskpart again it no longer shows any active partition or volume, and the system will not boot. I even tried pulling the plug while diskpart was still running, in case it was part of diskpart's closing process that was causing the problem. There are no other drives in the system, and I've also tried removing the WinPE drive.

*There are no errors*. Again, as long as I don't exit the diskpart tool it will show the partition as active, but the setting is gone as soon as diskpart closes.

How can I fix this? I need to be able to set the boot volume in a batch script from the WinPE environment.

Comment: Due to the fact, I am curious, why eactly are you attempting to mark the partition as active?  What problem are you trying to solve by doing that?

Comment: WinPE is the same as the recovery console. "On the Recovery Console, which is included in all Windows 2000, Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, there is a diskpart command which is significantly different from the one included in the actual operating system" https://superuser.com/a/597004/40928

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/a/597004/40928

Answer (score 0):

So my `diskpart` code was working just fine. I had somehow marked the disk in the bios boot menu as disabled. Move along; nothing to see here.